# Calculating the angle between Points

Tags: c++, opencv

Working with C++ and opencv

I am trying to calculate an angle between two points.....I have a 2D plane with a changing center point of a bounding box, Now if the center point in frame 1 has changed its location in frame 2 i need to find the angle of these two points.

Here is the example of what i am trying to do:

[image]

Can someone suggest a way of working this out.......? some kind of mathematical solution or perhaps a C++ function.

Comment: There is no angle between two points, just a line. You need two lines to define an angle. Where is the other line?

Comment: Yep, where is the angle? That said, depending on where your angle is, the atan2() function might be useful, too, but you need to improve your question/diagram to get a definite answer.

Comment: In fact, it would be useful if you could draw the angle on the image.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [Dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product):

```
v1.v2 = v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y

v1.v2 = |v1| * |v2| * cos(theta)
---------------------------------+
                                 |
                                 +-->  theta = acos(v1.v2 / |v1|*|v2|)
```

A sample code is:

```
float angleBetween(const Point &v1, const Point &v2)
{
    float len1 = sqrt(v1.x * v1.x + v1.y * v1.y);
    float len2 = sqrt(v2.x * v2.x + v2.y * v2.y);

    float dot = v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y;

    float a = dot / (len1 * len2);

    if (a >= 1.0)
        return 0.0;
    else if (a <= -1.0)
        return PI;
    else
        return acos(a); // 0..PI
}
```

It calculates angle between v1 and v2 as below image

[image]

Comment: Would you care to define the angle that is returned here? And we can see if it matches that required by @Tomazi

Comment: @David He just did, so I'm removing my comment: a picture says more than words here :)

Comment: I looked up a video on youtube on Dot Product http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDdR5s0C4cY,......and wondering why a & b both have three parameters.....Now in your case v would be Point data type variable....?

Comment: also find out that this is used for 3d plane where where am working with 2d plane

Comment: I think that video is in 3D space, my sample is in 2D space

Comment: ok i understand this now jut trying to work out few examples on paper :D before i can code it thx you

Comment: How come this is a solution? He is asking the angle between two points not vectors, without further information you can't define an angle between two points since the trajectory between two points are not given.

Comment: @CroCo: It doesn't calculate angle between points. According to the picture at the end of answer, it is calculating angle between two vectors made of two entry points.

Comment: Thank you for the function @deepmax, I've modified it a bit to include +/- angles. Simply return direction * acos(a); where: float direction = (v1.cross(v2) >= 0 ? 1.0 : -1.0); For those who don't fully understand how to use this function: v1 and v2 are the relative positions from the central point, i.e. v1 = p1 - pc, and v2 = p2 - pc, where pc is the central point where the angle is defined from p1 to p2 through pc.

Comment: Simplification: `float len1 = sqrt(v1.x * v1.x + v1.y * v1.y);` --> `float len1 = hypot(v1.x , v1.y);`  Available C99, I _think_ also in C++

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you want to calculate the angle between the two points relative to the origin of the 2D plane, you can use the dot product to calculate the angle between the points (like how the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15888243/1647057) of this question described).

OpenCV has implementations of calculating the dot product and the length of points. The dot product of two points is:

```
v1.dot(v2) // v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y
```

Length of vector (commonly referred as the L2 Norm of vector) using [`cv::norm`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#norm) is:

```
cv::norm(v1) // sqrt(v1.x * v1.x + v1.y * v1.y)
```

Using OpenCV's implementations of dot product and the length of vector we have the following sample code

```
double angle(const Point& v1, const Point& v2)
{
    double cosAngle = v1.dot(v2) / (cv::norm(v1) * cv::norm(v2));
    if (cosAngle > 1.0)
        return 0.0;
    else if (cosAngle < -1.0)
        return CV_PI;
    return std::acos(cosAngle);
}
```

This solution isn't only limited to 2D points. It can be used for calculating the angle between 3D points as well.

Note that angle is in [Radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian).

If you want degrees, you should multiply it by 180 / Pi:

```
return std::acos(cosAngle) * 180 / CV_PI
```